# Rust replacing char in string doesn't work

Tags: string, replace, rust, char

I wrote a little program in Rust that just doesn't work.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter a string: ");
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

    println!("you have entered:\n{}", input);

    println!("enter a char which you wish to replace: ");
    let mut char_to_be_replaced = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut char_to_be_replaced).unwrap();
    println!("you have entered: {}", char_to_be_replaced);

    println!("enter a replacement char:");
    let mut replacement_char = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut replacement_char).unwrap();
    println!("replacement char is: {}", replacement_char);

    let result = input.replace(&char_to_be_replaced, &replacement_char);
    println!("end result is: ");
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

input is "asd, asd"

char_to_be_replaced is ","

replacement_char is "."

to my horror **result** is **"asd, asd"** instead of **"asd. asd"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings end with a newline. You can use`trim` to remove them.